# Routing stdout of process with PPID Spoofing

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, stdout

I tried to write a code that uses `CreateProcess()` to execute `CMD` commands and will redirect the `stdout` to a named pipe. I wanted to add a functionality to spoof the Parent PID so that the cmd will spawn under explorer.exe. Each of the functionalities works on it's own but when I tried to merge them it will not work.

The stdout routing:

```
int main()
{
    HANDLE hStdout_Rd = NULL;
    HANDLE hStdout_Wr = NULL;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    CreatePipe(&hStdout_Rd, &hStdout_Wr, &saAttr, NULL);
    SetHandleInformation(hStdout_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);

    //Set startup info
    STARTUPINFO si;
    ZeroMemory(&si, (sizeof(STARTUPINFO)));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    si.hStdError = hStdout_Wr;
    si.hStdOutput = hStdout_Wr;
    si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    CString cmd;
    if (CreateProcess(NULL, cmd.GetBuffer(), NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        //Great success read pipe contents
    }
    CloseHandle(hStdout_Rd);
    CloseHandle(hStdout_Wr);
}
```

The PPID Spoof:

```
int main() {

    CString cmd;
    STARTUPINFOEXA sInfoEX;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo;
    SIZE_T sizeT;

    HANDLE expHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, getParentProcessID());

    ZeroMemory(&sInfoEX, sizeof(STARTUPINFOEXA));
    InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(NULL, 1, 0, &sizeT);
    sInfoEX.lpAttributeList = (LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, sizeT);
    InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(sInfoEX.lpAttributeList, 1, 0, &sizeT);
    UpdateProcThreadAttribute(sInfoEX.lpAttributeList, 0, PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS, &expHandle, sizeof(HANDLE), NULL, NULL);
    sInfoEX.StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOEXA);

    CreateProcessA(NULL, cmd.GetBuffer(), NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_SUSPENDED | CREATE_NO_WINDOW | EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT, NULL, NULL, reinterpret_cast<LPSTARTUPINFOA>(&sInfoEX), &pInfo);


    return 0;
}
```

All Together:

```
int main() {

    HANDLE hStdout_Rd = NULL;
    HANDLE hStdout_Wr = NULL;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    CString cmd;
    STARTUPINFOEXA sInfoEX;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&pInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    SIZE_T sizeT;

    HANDLE expHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, getParentProcessID());

    ZeroMemory(&sInfoEX, sizeof(STARTUPINFOEXA));
    sInfoEX.StartupInfo = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    sInfoEX.StartupInfo = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    sInfoEX.StartupInfo = hStdout_Wr;
    sInfoEX.StartupInfo = hStdout_Wr;
    sInfoEX.StartupInfo = SW_HIDE;
    InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(NULL, 1, 0, &sizeT);
    sInfoEX.lpAttributeList = (LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, sizeT);
    InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(sInfoEX.lpAttributeList, 1, 0, &sizeT);
    UpdateProcThreadAttribute(sInfoEX.lpAttributeList, 0, PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS, &expHandle, sizeof(HANDLE), NULL, NULL);
    sInfoEX.StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOEXA);

    if (CreateProcessA(NULL, cmd.GetBuffer(), NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_SUSPENDED | CREATE_NO_WINDOW | EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT, NULL, NULL, reinterpret_cast<LPSTARTUPINFOA>(&sInfoEX), &pInfo))
    {
        //Read pipe contents
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: when you use `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS` - *Attributes inherited from the specified process include handles...* - so handles of pipes in your process will be not inherited. you need duplicate this handles to parent (explorer) and use duplicated values in *si.hStdOutput,si.hStdInput,si.hStdError*, also use `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST` for inherit only this handles

Comment: I could not quit understand where am I supposed to copy the handle. Am i supposed to change the PROCESS_INFORMATION of explorer.exe and set it's stdout handles to ones I created? If so I'm not sure how to do so. If you could point me to a code sample that would be very much appreciated. Thank you very much

Comment: `si.hStdOutput` - must be handle value of pipe in explorer but not in your process

Comment: After Opening the handle to explorer I duplicate the strout_Rd handle the following way: ```DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), hStdOut_Rd, hExplorer, &dupHandle,0,FALSE,DUPLICATE_SAME_CLASS_); ``` and set the StartupInfo.hStdoOutput to dupHandle. I also changed PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS to PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST but now CreateProcess fails.

Comment: sample code will be big enough. of course not hard write it, but for what need at all exec cmd from another process ?

Comment: I want the logs to look like the execution of the CMD command was under explorer and not the original process.

Comment: and are will be different in logs cmd exec from explorer vs your process (if your process not run elevated, service, etc) ? also why not use `CreateProcessAsUser` in this case with explorer token ?

Comment: formal code like [this](https://github.com/rbmm/MISC/blob/master/redirect.cpp) can be used. but not sure that you need change parent process at all.

Comment: yes, `CreateProcessAsUser` Does not change parent process id (without `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS`). but almost nobody look for this anyway. and you not need `SE_DEBUG_PRIV`

Comment: `DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), hStdOut_Rd, hExplorer, &dupHandle,0, TRUE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE);` must be - *These handles must be created as inheritable handles* - so 6 parameter of `DuplicateHandle` must be TRUE but not  FALSE. also you need use `DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE` for at once close this pipe handle in self process. and after call `CreateProcess` - close handle in explorer again via `DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE`. but i still not view sense in change inherited process id

Comment: @Manor_Solomon Do you want to route output to explorer.exe or your own process? Since you write `//Read pipe contents` after `CreateProcess()`.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT - output going to pipe, but not to any process

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a Powershell script solution that meets the OP requests and matches what he tried to do. It embeds C# code from the [decoder-it/psgetsystem](https://github.com/decoder-it/psgetsystem/blob/master/psgetsys.ps1)  with minor change for the PPID spoofing and I added the redirection of STDOut and STDErr from the spawned process to the console running the script with an anonymous pipe.  It’s probably not very clean code but it works !

Ex of usage from Administrator Powershell prompt:

```
> Start-service TrustedInstaller  
> .\ThisScript.ps1 (Get-Process TrustedInstaller).Id cmd.exe '/C whoami'
```

```
$mycode = @"
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class MyProcess
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetLastError();
    
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool CreateProcess(
        string lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, bool bInheritHandles, uint dwCreationFlags,
        IntPtr lpEnvironment, string lpCurrentDirectory, [In] ref STARTUPINFOEX lpStartupInfo,
        out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UpdateProcThreadAttribute(
        IntPtr lpAttributeList, uint dwFlags, IntPtr Attribute, IntPtr lpValue,
        IntPtr cbSize, IntPtr lpPreviousValue, IntPtr lpReturnSize);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(
        IntPtr lpAttributeList, int dwAttributeCount, int dwFlags, ref IntPtr lpSize);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool DeleteProcThreadAttributeList(IntPtr lpAttributeList);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
    
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool CreatePipe(out IntPtr hReadPipe, out IntPtr hWritePipe, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpPipeAttributes, uint nSize);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SetHandleInformation(IntPtr hObject,uint dwMask,uint dwFlags);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool ReadFile(IntPtr hFile, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, uint nNumberOfBytesToRead, out uint lpNumberOfBytesRead, IntPtr lpOverlapped);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool WriteFile(IntPtr hFile, byte [] lpBuffer, uint nNumberOfBytesToWrite, out uint lpNumberOfBytesWritten, [In] ref System.Threading.NativeOverlapped lpOverlapped);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool DuplicateHandle(IntPtr hSourceProcessHandle, IntPtr hSourceHandle, IntPtr hTargetProcessHandle, out IntPtr lpTargetHandle,
    uint dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, uint dwOptions);

    
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    struct STARTUPINFOEX
    {
        public STARTUPINFO StartupInfo;
        public IntPtr lpAttributeList;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    struct STARTUPINFO
    {
        public Int32 cb;
        public string lpReserved;
        public string lpDesktop;
        public string lpTitle;
        public Int32 dwX;
        public Int32 dwY;
        public Int32 dwXSize;
        public Int32 dwYSize;
        public Int32 dwXCountChars;
        public Int32 dwYCountChars;
        public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
        public Int32 dwFlags;
        public Int16 wShowWindow;
        public Int16 cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public int dwProcessId;
        public int dwThreadId;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public int nLength;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
        public bool bInheritHandle;
    }
    public static void CreateProcessFromParent(int ppid, string command, string cmdargs)
    {
        const uint EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT = 0x00080000;
        const uint CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010;
        const int PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS = 0x00020000;
        const uint DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS = 0x00000002;
        const uint DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE = 0x00000001;
        const uint HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT = 0x00000001;
        const int STARTF_USESTDHANDLES = 0x00000100;
        const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
        const uint BUFSIZE = 4096; 
    
        IntPtr phChildStd_OUT_Rd = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr phChildStd_OUT_Wr = IntPtr.Zero;
        var pipAttr = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        pipAttr.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(pipAttr);
        pipAttr.bInheritHandle = true; 
        pipAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;
        var pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        var si = new STARTUPINFOEX();
        IntPtr lpValue = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr pPipeDupHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr pParentProcHandle = Process.GetProcessById(ppid).Handle;
        
        Console.WriteLine("[+] Got Handle {1} for ppid: {0}", ppid, pParentProcHandle);
                                
        Process.EnterDebugMode();
        
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[+]Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT.");
            if (! CreatePipe(out phChildStd_OUT_Rd, out phChildStd_OUT_Wr, ref pipAttr, 0)) {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("[!]Error: " + GetLastError() +", to create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT.");
                return ;
            }
        
            IntPtr pThisProcHandle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;
            pPipeDupHandle = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(IntPtr.Size);
            if ( ! DuplicateHandle(pThisProcHandle, phChildStd_OUT_Wr, pParentProcHandle, 
                                out pPipeDupHandle, 0, true, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS) ) {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("[!]Error: " + GetLastError() + ", to Duplicate handle of the pipe");
                return ;
            }
        
            // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.
            if ( ! SetHandleInformation(phChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) ) {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("[!]Error: " + GetLastError() + ", to read handle of the pipe");
                return ;
            }
            si.StartupInfo.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
            si.StartupInfo.hStdError = pPipeDupHandle;
            si.StartupInfo.hStdOutput = pPipeDupHandle;
            si.StartupInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
            
            var lpSize = IntPtr.Zero;
            InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(IntPtr.Zero, 1, 0, ref lpSize);
            si.lpAttributeList = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(lpSize);
            if ( ! InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(si.lpAttributeList, 1, 0, ref lpSize) ) {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("[!]Error: " + GetLastError() + ", to Initialize the process attribute list");
                return ;
            }
            lpValue = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(IntPtr.Size);
            Marshal.WriteIntPtr(lpValue, pParentProcHandle);
            
            if ( ! UpdateProcThreadAttribute(si.lpAttributeList, 0, (IntPtr)PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS,
                                             lpValue, (IntPtr)IntPtr.Size, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero) )          {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("[!]Error: " + GetLastError() + ", to Update the process attribute list with PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS");
                return ;
            }
            
            var pattr = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
            var tattr = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
            pattr.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(pattr);
            tattr.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(tattr);
            Console.Write("[+] Starting " + cmdargs  + " ... ");
            if ( CreateProcess(command, cmdargs, ref pattr, ref tattr, true, EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
                                 IntPtr.Zero, null, ref si, out pi) ) {
                Console.WriteLine("SUCCES - pid: " + pi.dwProcessId );}
            else {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("ERROR: " + GetLastError() + ", with the CreateProcess call");  }   
        }
        finally
        {
            if (si.lpAttributeList != IntPtr.Zero)  {
                DeleteProcThreadAttributeList(si.lpAttributeList);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(si.lpAttributeList);
            }
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(lpValue);
            if (pi.hProcess != IntPtr.Zero)         {
                CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
            }
            if (pi.hThread != IntPtr.Zero)          {
                CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
            }
            if (phChildStd_OUT_Wr != IntPtr.Zero)   {
                CloseHandle(phChildStd_OUT_Wr);
            }
            if (pPipeDupHandle != IntPtr.Zero)      {
                if ( ! DuplicateHandle(pParentProcHandle, pPipeDupHandle, IntPtr.Zero, 
                                out pPipeDupHandle, 0, false, DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE) ) 
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("[!]Error: " + GetLastError() + ", to Close the duplicated handle of the pipe"); 
            }
        }
        
        bool bSuccess = false;
        uint dwRead, dwWritten; 
        byte[] chBuf = new byte[BUFSIZE]; 
        IntPtr hThisStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        var ol = new System.Threading.NativeOverlapped();
            
        for ( ; ; ) { 
            bSuccess = ReadFile( phChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, out dwRead, IntPtr.Zero);
            if( ! bSuccess || dwRead == 0 ) break; 

            bSuccess = WriteFile(hThisStdOut, chBuf, dwRead, out dwWritten, ref ol);
            if (! bSuccess ) break; 
        } 
        if (phChildStd_OUT_Rd != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                CloseHandle(phChildStd_OUT_Rd);
            }
    }
}
"@
 Add-Type -TypeDefinition $mycode

#Autoinvoke?
 $cmdargs=$args[1]
if($args.Length -eq 3)
{
  $cmdargs= $args[1] + " " + $args[2]
}

[MyProcess]::CreateProcessFromParent($args[0],[NullString]::Value,$cmdargs)
```